# How can I insert a byte into a nested byte array at an specific position?

Tags: c#, insert, byte, arrays, nested-lists

I have multiple byte lists (*lines*) inside another list (nested lists). How can I insert a specific byte at an specific index at an specific line?

```
byte ByteToInsert = 1;
int LineNumber = 2;
int IndexInSubList = 3;

// Create top-level list
List<List<byte>> NestedList = new List<List<byte>>();

// Create two nested lists
List<byte> Line1 = new List<byte> { 2, 2, 5, 25 };
List<byte> Line2 = new List<byte> { 3, 7, 8, 35 };

// Add to top-level list
NestedList.Add(Line1);
NestedList.Add(Line2);

// Insert
...
```

After executing the insert code, NestedLists should consist of two lines:

```
{ 2, 2, 5, 25 }
{ 3, 7, 8, 1, 35 }
```

How can I accomplish this?

### Solution

*thanks to Hamlet Hakobyan and Marc Gravell♦:*

If a single byte is to be inserted:

```
NestedList[LineNumber - 1].Insert(IndexInSubList, ByteToInsert);
```

If a byte array is to be inserted:

```
NestedList[LineNumber - 1].InsertRange(IndexInSubList, BytesToInsert);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the nested list collection also by indexer. Then use `Insert` method to insert data at the position you need.

```
NestedList[LineNumber-1].Insert(IndexInSubList, ByteToInsert);
```

Comment: If ByteToInsert is an byte array, can I use `for` to loop through it?

Comment: @Jacobus21 if `ByteToInsert` is a `byte[]`, then it is very badly named! But: `InsertRange`